# The field "str_mara" is unknown, but there is a field with the similar name "it_mara"

Tags: abap

I want to display the content of Mara table.

```
types : begin of str_mara,
          matnr type mara-matnr,
          ernam type mara-ernam,
        end of str_mara.

data it_mara type table of str_mara .

select matnr ernam from mara into TABLE it_mara .

loop at it_mara into str_mara.
  write:/ str_mara-matnr , str_mara-ernam.
endloop.
```

Comment: That's all the difference between a variable and a type...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to select all the entries from `MARA` table into an internal table without using any critera?

Comment: Exactly same question asked on [SCN](https://answers.sap.com/questions/708310/sap-abap-the-field-str-mara-is-unknown-but-there-i.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type is just a static definition, no memory is allocated, therefore cannot be used on its own.

You can either create a variable with that type or use a inline declaration to create a variable like that.

- option 1: `data ls_mara type str_mara.`
- option 2: `loop at lt_mara into data(ls_mara).`

Or go with Umar's answer :)

BTW, be sure to check your where condition on the access to mara table.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is no variable named `str_mara`. There is just a type named `str_mara`.

Just loop using a field symbol as it should be done anyway.

```
LOOP AT it_mara ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<str_mara>).
   WRITE: /, <str_mara>-matnr, <str_mara>-ernam.
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use inline declaration to display content of mara table with fewer line of ABAP code.

```
SELECT matnr, ernam FROM mara INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_mara) .
LOOP AT lt_mara ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_mara>).
   WRITE: /, <fs_mara>-matnr, <fs_mara>-ernam.
ENDLOOP.
```